# Play WSClient stream timeout

Tags: java, playframework, akka, playframework-2.5

I want to consume Server-Sent Events in my Play 2.5 app. The Content-Type of the API endpoint is `text/event-stream`.

I'm having difficulty with setting the timeout for the REST call.
When I set the request timeout to `-1` - for which the request should never timeout - `whenComplete` is called without an exception after 120 seconds.

```
    CompletionStage<StreamedResponse> events = ws.url("https://example.com/events")
            .setMethod("GET")
            .setHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream")
            .setRequestTimeout(-1)
            .stream();
    events.thenCompose(res -> {
        Source<ByteString, ?> responseBody = res.getBody();
        return responseBody.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString("\n"), Integer.MAX_VALUE, FramingTruncation.ALLOW)).map(ByteString::utf8String).runForeach(data -> logger.info(data), materializer);
    }).whenComplete((done, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable != null) {
            logger.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
        }
        logger.info("Done");
    });
```

When I set the RequestTimeout to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the request doesn't timeout after 120 seconds. However it would probably then timeout the request after ~25 days.

How can I set the timeout to infinite?

Comment: Seems to be this issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4846. Although there they claim it's solved with version 2.5.

Comment: Well, when I change the call to `.setRequestTimeout(-1).get()` instead of `stream()`  like in the bug report the request doesn't timeout after 120 seconds. So it might be related but isn't the actual reported issue.
However `get()` won't help me with server-sent events and akka streams.
Thanks Kris. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Uhm, I missed the streaming part.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, you are using AhcWSClient

```
val client = AhcWSClient()
```

You can then do,

```
client.url("www.streamingurl.com")
.withMethod("GET")
.withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf)
.stream()
```

Comment: You are posting scala code, my issue is with the java API.